# Which traces should I fill / pour?

Tags: pcb-design, trace, copper-pour

What are the general rules of filling / pouring traces? What traces should I pour?

I assume ground is poured most often.
Should I pour other traces? Supply/Signal or something else perhaps?
What are the advantages/disadvantages of pouring?

If specifics are needed then assume an analog low-power audio circuit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming two layer board the most common practice is to pour the ground on both sides.

There are three reasons i can think of using a pour for other then a general ground. First, in a multi layer board (4 or more layers) one inside layer is a power pour and the other is a ground pour. Second, when running very large power traces it's easier to run a regular skinny trace and then use a pour to make it larger. Finally a pour can be used to heat sink components like D-Pack MOSFETs (turn off thermals in that case) and voltage regulators. In the case of regulators the tab is on the ground plane but similar to the MOSFET thermals on just the regulator need turned off.

Comment: In my case I am talking about a single layer board. Are you saying that in general only one trace is poured per layer?

Comment: There's no hard fast rule. A pour is a tool to expand a particular NET not trace, it just happens that traces are tied to NETs. This may be better able to explain it then i can.http://dangerousprototypes.com/2012/07/18/eagle-polygons/

Comment: Thanks, I kind of meant nets not traces, but seems to make sense to me both ways.

Answer (score 1):

Generally for single-layer boards you'll want to pour your ground. This is to improve the signal integrity. Suppose you have a trace that carries a clock signal. It's always best to have the return path (ground) very close to the signal trace, so that it doesn't have to loop around the board to "find" its return. Having a ground pour helps keep the return path very close to the signal trace(s) and helps prevent losses. It also helps shield the trace  against external noise and interference that could affect your signal quality (think differential pairs, in a way). For low-speed signals this isn't as critical, but if you're in the high kHz or MHz range, you'll definitely want a pour, and/or differential pairs.